# Android 4.1.2 - Carousel not work inside the ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, carousel, android-4.1-jelly-bean

In my app I have a Fragment that has ViewPager inside a ScrollView. One of the Fragment in this ViewPager has a Carousel view. This Carousel is developed base on http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel.

My problem is Carousel doesn't spin in Android 4.1.2 in this layout setup. When I run the Carousel Fragment Standalone it works perfectly. But inside the ViewPager it doesn't. I'm supporting this app Android API 16 and up. Except for API 16 it work for all others.

On scroll and on touch events works in the same way as it runs in other Android versions. I couldn't isolate the problem any further. I tried all the way that it comes to my mind. Finally I have run out of tricks. Appreciate your support. Thanks in advance.

Here are my layouts.

ViewPager Fragment

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.authentic.fragment.ShowDetailsFragment">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewShowDetailsBg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/hint"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/phone_shows_detail_bg" />

<com.authentic.view.ParallaxScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollViewShowDetails"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewShowDetailsHeader"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/height_show_details_header_image"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/hint"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/phone_show_header" />

        <com.authentic.view.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator
            android:id="@+id/tabPageIndicatorShowDetails"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:background="@color/green_dull"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
            android:paddingRight="3dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewShowDetailsHeader" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPagerShowDetails"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/height_show_details_view_pager"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tabPageIndicatorShowDetails">

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    </RelativeLayout>
</com.authentic.view.ParallaxScrollView>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutShowDetailsBack"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="17.5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="19dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hint"
        android:src="@drawable/show_back_arrow" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewShowDetailsBack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="@string/label_back"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</LinearLayout></RelativeLayout>
```

Carousel Fragment

```
<com.authentic.widget.carousel.Carousel   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/carouselShowCharacter"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_gravity="top"
     tools:context="com.authentic.fragment.ShowDetailCharactersFragment"
     android:foregroundGravity="top">
```

Comment: With further investigation I found that the Carousel Fragment layout is continuously creating. Found that onLayout is called by the looper non stop. However can't find from which the looper get the message. If I flag the onLayout method in the Carousel class that can solve my problem  but still I'm getting the call and it want stop. Still this solution will be a patch. Any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: hi...did you find any solution for this? i need to implement carousel in a fragment which is inside a viewpager...

Comment: Yes I solved this, the problem was not in this. Due to some other view the parent view of this was recreated continuously. I stopped that recreation and solved the problem.